# reference needed: Dirichlet L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions

Where is the logarithmic derivative at $s=0$ of the L-function of a Dirichlet character computed? Many people cite the Hurwitz formula but I was unable to find a suitable reference.

Comment: Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112688/the-value-of-a-dirichlet-l-function-and-its-derivative-at-s-0.

Comment: In this post there is a formula for the logarithmic derivative but no further reference (only the computation of the value $L(0, \chi)$ is discussed). I already know the formula. What I want is a reference in which it is proved.

Comment: See Lemma 3.1 in http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/az4.pdf‎ with $k=2$.